# Ubuntu 22.04 freezes randomly

Tags: kernel, 22.04, freeze

Description of freeze:

- First the screen freezes but the cursor remains reactive for few seconds.
- Sometimes the screen goes black.
- Any music playing at that time continues playing without any problems.
- Can't switch to `ctrl-alt-fx` terminals after the freeze.
- Have noticed freezing more often while charging.

System info:

- OS: `Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS`
- Linux kernel: `6.0.0-060000-generic` (Upgraded to this for resolving another issue with bluetooth. The freezing issue was occurring before this change as well)

Hardware info:

- Model: `ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ROG Zephyrus G15 GA503RW`
- Processor: `AMD® Ryzen 9 6900hs with radeon graphics × 16`
- GPU: `Geforce RTX 3070 Ti Laptop GPU`

Please ask for any additional info required. Will post here. Thanks.